# Section 'Global Slack Notifier Setting' not showing after installing "Slack Notification Plugin" in my configure section of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, slack

My Jenkins Version is 2.190.1

I need to ask regarding the implementation of slack notifications in jenkins , although i have gone through many of the tutorials, but the problem is i have installed the plugin successfully when i go to configure Jenkins , Section of "Global Slack Notifier Setting" is missing although slack notification dropdown is shown in post-build section of the Job but not in configure where we used to add these two information

**Team Subdomain &
Integration Token **

i am only just able to see this section in Jenkins->Configure section

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is correct, why are you expecting to see something different? `Global Slack Notifier Setting` is related to obsolete Global Slack notifier plugin, Slack Notification plugin doesn't have such option

Comment: but where i would have to put my [ Team Subdomain & Integration ] info , because almost every tutorial  showing "Global Slack Notifier Setting" where they add this info ,  i am unable to see this section where i put these , hope you understand ?

Comment: Team subdomain is your workspace, integration token must be stored in credential. They've updated the plugin and remove/rename some options

Comment: Have a look a setup [instructions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin) on github

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I do appreciate your effort ! But here again is the issue, i checked out the link it also shows  "Global Slack Notifier Setting"   under "Install Instructions for Slack compatible application", that section is not showing in my scenario ! i am unable to see that in my jenkins. !

Comment: Well, as I've already told, the plugin was updated and some options were removed. Our Jenkins instance has the same options with your screenshot and it works fine

Comment: Yes, Got it , Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @giturr14 is correct. For the sake of completeness, I want to add that,

- The team sub-domain must be entered under "workspace"
- The integration token must be entered via credential->Add, then select "secret text" and enter the token under secrets, give id and description.

Then select your secret and press "test connection".

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me. I figured out that you dont need to add ".slack.com" after your workspace. so DONT DO "workspaceexample.slack.com" DO "workspaceexample". This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is shown as Slack and we need to add slack credentials in credentials page.
 And then import them in here
[image: Here]